# How to join specific key in list in Python?

Tags: python

For example I have item like this `({'id': u'20509:28341', 'title': u'\u9ed1\u8272'}, {'id': u'1627207:28315', 'title': u'M'})`. What is the best way to join all 'id' in string by coma?

In the result I should get `20509:28341,1627207:28315`.

Comment: Is that a tuple of dicts?

Comment: @unwind yes, it is

Comment: ','.join(map(lambda x: x['id'] , a))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
>>> data = ({'id': u'20509:28341', 'title': u'\u9ed1\u8272'}, {'id': u'1627207:28315', 'title': u'M'})
>>> ",".join(x["id"] for x in data)
u'20509:28341,1627207:28315'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> t=({'id': u'20509:28341', 'title': u'\u9ed1\u8272'}, {'id': u'1627207:28315', 'title': u'M'})
>>> ','.join(i['id'] for i in t)
'20509:28341,1627207:28315'
>>>
```